# Why is Procfile not recognised by Heroku?

Tags: flask, heroku, deployment, web-deployment

I'm trying to deploy a flask app to heroku, but I keep on getting the error:
`Scaling dynos... !  ▸  Couldn't find that process type (web).`
whenever I try to run `heroku ps:scale web=1`.

However, when I run `heroku ps:scale`, it tells me that I need to `Upload a Procfile to add process types.`

I do have a Procfile located in my root directory, and it is capitalised and doesn't have any file extensions. I have tried deleting and recreating the Procfile, but this hasn't produced any results.

How do I get Heroku to recognise my Procfile?

Here is what I've been trying to do:
[ubuntu terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4ZOi.png)

Comment: What's in the `Procfile`?

Comment: Verify `Procfile` is correctly spelled. Verify it is located at the root level of your git repo. Verify it is committed. Verify to which branch it is committed. Verify which branch you are deploying to Heroku.
If any of them is faulty then Heroku won't see `Procfile`.

Comment: @v25 My Procfile only contains this :`web:gunicorn app:app`

Comment: @TinNguyen Yep, I've met all those conditions and it still isn't working.

Comment: Show your git repo and all the commands you do to deploy your app on Heroku.

Comment: @TinNguyen I've edited the post to include those.

Comment: You haven't proven that Procfile is commited to git. You haven't created a new commit.

Comment: @TinNguyen I have updated it once again to include me commiting the Procfile to github.

Comment: check with `git ls-files --error-unmatch Procfile` if it is versioned. You could have put it into .gitignore. You haven't create a new commit. Change a file and commit or do `git commit --allow-empty`

Comment: @TinNguyen I made an empty commit, and made sure it isn't in the .gitignore, and it still doesn't work. I have even deleted it, commited it, added it then commited it again, and it still isn't recognised. I used `git ls-files --error-unmatch Procfile` and this has only returned `Procfile`, so I presume that means it is not versioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to create a new git repo and heroku app, and copy the code over for it to work.